# Summing Columns In Array Based on Specific Criteria

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a page in PHP more efficient. The goal is to tally payments for jobs that were delivered between two dates. The payments are in a separate table but only have a payment date, not a delivery date. Previously, I had a `while` loop to select all records between two dates which then carried out another query on the payments table within the loop. This was painfully slow so i have done this in 2 queries and put the results into an array as shown below.

```
{ [20253]=> array(5) { ["contNo"]=> string(5) "20253" ["contDate"]=> string(19) "2017-01-25 15:15:34" ["hireStart"]=> string(10) "2017-01-27" ["hireEnd"]=> string(10) "2017-01-30" ["revenue"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["contNo"]=> string(5) "20253" ["revenue"]=> string(6) "197.85" } [1]=> array(2) { ["contNo"]=> string(5) "20253" ["revenue"]=> string(5) "70.22" } } }
```

What i would now like to do is sum the `revenue` when the `hireStart` date is between `x` and `y` dates and also sum the `revenue` when the `contDate` is between `x` and `y` date.

Does anyone have an idea how I can do this? Just to point out that is just one record in the array of 14000 results so efficiency is what i need most! The code used to generate the array is below.

```
while ($contNums = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
    //for each contract in date range sum revenue
    $contNoArray[$contNums['contNo']]=$contNums;
}
mysqli_free_result($result2);

$stmt2="SELECT contNo, revenue FROM `payments`";
$result3 = $conn->query($stmt2);
while ($payments = $result3->fetch_assoc()) {
    $contNoArray[$payments['contNo']]['revenue'][]=$payments;
}
foreach($contNoArray AS $contract)
{
    This is where i am stuck!
}
```

Comment: Why not just use the database to get the sum? 14k rows should take almost no time. This sounds like something that could be done with a single query in under a second.

Comment: I couldn’t do this because the hireStart date is in the contracts table where the revenue is in a second table which does not have the hireStart date. Previously I was doing a query on the second table within the while loop but this was very slow!

Comment: You can join the data from multiple tables. Or even run two queries grouping on some common value and join afterwards.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean just do a left outer join on the contNo field from the payments table to the contracts table. I will try this but would still like to know if it is possible to do it in the way I started out! Thanks for your help by the way

Comment: A left join will probably be the fastest way to accomplish this in one query. Should be significantly faster than application side logic also, provided your tables are correctly indexed (everything in your `WHERE` and `ON` clauses should be indexed).

Comment: The way to do this in just php is probably exactly how you are doing it. Brute force looping over an array and summing values. You could also do your summing when you are building the initial array. No reason to loop over again at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jonathan that suggested the left join. Should have thought of this before! I would still like to know how (code wise) to do it as i was initially attempting if anyone does know. The solution to do it in the query is below...

```
SELECT sum(P.revenue) as revTotal
FROM contracts C LEFT JOIN payments P
ON P.contNo = C.contNo
where C.contDate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
```